# Why it is called "form control"?

Tags: html

From [HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#introduction-1):

> A form is a component of a Web page that has form controls, such as
>   text fields, buttons, checkboxes, range controls, or colour pickers.

From this saying we can tell that "form control" is an element of a form,i think it should be called by form element,But-

1. Why it is called "form control"?
2. is there is any need of the word "control"?

Comment: Source of the quote?

Comment: It's a UI term. Also if a form control was a "form element" then what would <form> be? (Similarly have you ever wondered why they're called "forms"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Element has a specific meaning in HTML, and so does *something* element. A form element is what you get with `<form>`.

A form control is what you get with `<input>`, `<select>`, `<button>` and `<textarea>`.

Meanwhile, inputs et al have been called controls in UIs since before HTML existed.